# How to install/configure mod_reqtimeout in Apache

Tags: apache, security

I need to configure mod_reqtimeout in my Apache server v2.2.22 (in a linux machine). Problem is, I have absolutely no clue on how to do it.

I checked the Apache site on this module [at this link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html) but there was no download/configuration details given.
Can someone help me on this ? Any help is much appreciated. Basically,

```
Is there something needed to download ?
If not, which files do I need to edit and how?
```

Comment: Needs to go on serverFault?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a standard Apache module from 2.2.15 and later, **but** is apparently missing in some distro versions (e.g. [Ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/562531), [FreeBSD](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-ports/2010-May/061337.html)).

First, check that `mod_reqtimeout` exists (e.g. look in `apache2/modules/` or - depending on your system - do something like `/usr/sbin/httpd -l | grep mod_reqtimeout`). Second, if it is, make sure it's enabled in your Apache config.

`mod_reqtimeout` is [available from GitHub](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/2.2.x/modules/filters/mod_reqtimeout.c) (also see the [RPM resource](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=apache-mod_reqtimeout)). Finally, this thread has [some useful tips](http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=45230). BTW FYI I don't think it can be enabled in an .htaccess file.

Comment: many thanks. I do find the mod_reqtimeout in the module directory. But where do I make the changes to enable it ? in httpd.conf ?

Comment: Yes, check the Apache config file to ensure that it is enabled: look for something like `--enable-reqtimeout`

Comment: There is no entry for 'reqtimeout' in the httpd.conf file . Also, the module file is not a '.c' file but a '.so' file. Will I need to install it or something ?

Comment: try adding the required entry to `httpd.config` and check for errors... but take a look to see if it's in your Apache install's `mods-available` dir.

Comment: PS Apache will load .so modules on restart: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_so.html - also try Apache's `enmod` command if it's in `mods-available` but not `mods-enabled`.